# Rails protect_from_forgery has not been defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-token-auth

I'm new at rails so maybe this is so basic and that's why I couldn't find anything about it. But anyways I stuck at here and I need help.

I updated a rails 4 application to rails 6 and when I try to sign_in it throws this error.

```
ArgumentError at /v1/auth/sign_in
=================================

Before process_action callback :protect_from_forgery has not been defined
```

I'm using devise 4.8.1 and devise_token_auth 1.2.0 but I couldn't found any solution for this problem. I tried many things but any of them didn't worked.

Comment: Make sure you follow the upgrade guides when changing rails versions: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html
Also, go version by version. In your case 4.0 > 4.1 > 4.2 > 5.0 > 5.1 > 5.2 > 6.0 > 6.1
If that's the only thing that's broken after 8 version updates, it's basically a miracle ! :D

Comment: No we already did it like you mentioned, but we didn't see this error. It occurs in the api part of the project but login function is working well in web side. But there isn't any controller in the api side, it's managing by devise itself

Answer (score 0):

Remove `protect_from_forgery` from your controllers. [Rails >=5.2 already has :protect_from_forgery on `ActionController::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/ec4a836919c021c0a5cf9ebeebb4db5e02104a55) by default.

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked